Alt Affiliations on APS Papers
I'm preparing my first paper for submission to PRX Quantum and utilising RevTex for this.
I've noticed that there is an \altaffiliation macro for providing alternate affiliations (presumably).
I'm in the position of currently being affiliated with two universities (one for my PhD and one for a separate Masters that I'm doing concurrently) but the paper I'm writing is solely to do with one of the universities.
Should I list my other university using this or not?

\altaffiliation produces a footnote, and would be used for stating, e.g., a present or permanent address. If you want to state two (or more) affiliations on equal footing, you'd use multiple \affiliation macros for the same author.
That said, in the current case, where the work is only supported by, and has solely to do with one of your universities, you should really only list that affiliation.

If the work is done at and under the direction of faculty at one of the universities, that affiliation is all that is required (opinion). In particular, if this is doctoral work, I'd think it a bit superfluous, though harmless, to list both.
Affiliation does two things. One, it indicates support from some institution and, two, it lets people find you. But these are often separated, though there is some (strong) disagreement with not stating an affiliation with some place that financially and legally supports you and the work.
